# AWS Lambda layers query with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to move working code from my local machine to AWS Lambda. This is a primarily a data wrangling code which generates a pdf file.

I am trying to add a AWS layer AWSSDKPandas-Python38 but this consumes too much space and for other layers I start getting the message *Layers consume more than the available size of 262144000 bytes*. When I put pandas under a custom layer I get below error:

> "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --force' to build the C extensions first.",
> "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
> "stackTrace": []

Also, I have reached after similar issues with numpy for which I resorted to AWS layer: AWSLambda-Python38-SciPy1x. There used to be a AWS layer for data wrangling which worked earlier for most of my deployments but cant find it now.

Regards,
dbeings

Comment: Its better to use container lambdas for dependencies, then layers.

Comment: Thanks, will explore containers / Docker. But one question as I am not well versed with devops / infra setup . I am doing dev on windows personal machine and then deploying to AWS Lambda. Would there be additional charges for services like AWS ECR or other complexities / charges. I have been using Lambda more for POCs and have found AWS free limits to be fairly liberal for Lambda - just wanted to check if I need to be wary of additional charges of any new service once I move to containers.     

Earlier, AWSDataWrangler-Python39 took care of Pandas and Numpy - cant find it now in AWS layers